# SceneKit – How to set the zoom on the default SCNCamera?

Tags: ios, view, zooming, scenekit, pinch

### Basically put, my problem:

I have searched the Apple Docs for some form of "zoom" applied to the default camera, but I can't find one. I have also tried creating my own camera (instead of using the default one) but for other reasons, this will not work. I need to use the default camera, but I need to figure out how to remove this property of initial "zoom." Is it even possible to change certain values of the default camera without creating my own camera?

---

### What do I mean by "zoom?":

When I say zoom, I'm referring to the fact that when I open the scene, I can't see very much. When I pinch my fingers inward, I "zoom out" of the scene so that I can see more (and the stuff in the distance gets smaller). See this image to further understand what I mean:

[image]

As you can see in this image, the left is what the default camera gives me every time I open the scene. What I instead want is on the right. It is "zoomed out."

---

### What I have tried:

I have tried several things. Some of these are already explained above.

• First off, I have already tried to make my own camera instead of changing the values on the default camera. However, creating my own camera changes some other things in my app that I can't have. So what I really need is to change this "zoom" value on the default camera.

• I have also tried searching the Apple Docs for this variable/property. I cannot find anything that I need. Unless I am wrong. If it seems pretty obvious what the solution is, just tell it to me! Nothing is working for me (partly because I don't 100% know how to use all the SCNCamera settings).

• I have also tried offsetting everything backwards (-z) from the camera. "If I can't zoom out, then I'll just push everything farther away!" But no, this does not work. Again, it has to do with some of the other features in my app. I can't have it conflict with the other necessities of the game.

---

### What do I need from you?:

I don't necessarily need some code. Code would, of course, be great! But it's not necessary. I just can't figure out how to access this property.

Also, if I am wrong in my reasoning at all, let me know. That way, I can more-easily figure out the solution on my own. For example, is it actually a "zoom" property, or is it merely the position of the camera changing when I pinch my fingers. What *does* pinching my fingers do, anyway? Can I mirror the pinching with a few lines of code, before the scene even displays? Etc etc.

Comment: I think you'll find it's the [x and y field of view angles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNCamera_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNCamera/xFov) that are changed by the pinch gesture with the default setup (for perspective projections...). I don't believe there's anything special about the default camera, you should be able to create a camera with the same settings and see the same projection.

Comment: Why not print various parameters to see what's changing when you pinch then duplicate it in code? For example, to follow up on @lock's suggestion, `print(camera.xFov)`. Or `print(camera.position.z)`.

Comment: @bpedit That's a good idea. I should have thought about it.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a Camera Node, and then add it to your SceneView:

```
//add Camera Node
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()

// Add Camera Node Position
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 50)

//add Camera Node to SceneView
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
sceneView.scene = scene
```