# Adding Zoom-in functionality in ARKit Session(camera view not the AR object)

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, arview

I am working on an app with ARKit, and want to detect objects at some distance by using ARKit camera session. Could anyone help if we can add any zoom in functionality to the AR Camera view?

Although did not find any concrete answer to this question but, some people suggested to transform the ARView itself which I think cannot be the right solution. Also, few talked about adding gesture on ARView and do some transforming but not accepted. Please help if anyone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding and experience in ARKit, camera zooming is not supported in ARKit. But you can zoom on the ArView.

Check this link please:
[Reference to camera zoom issue ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64896064/can-i-use-zoom-with-arview#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20use%20the,ArView%20like%20Andy%20Jazz%27s%20answer.&text=Save%20this%20answer.,-Show%20activity%20on)

[Another reference regarding scenekit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1523171-allowscameracontrol)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Mostafa.. but this answer I have already gone through and transforming the arView might create issues.. as it will still be capturing the frames. And main thing is I want to read frame from a certain distance by zooming the camera frames itself.. Please let me know if you come across any other suggestions please.

Comment: Did you try this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991326/scenekit-how-to-set-the-zoom-on-the-default-scncamera